# I promise, never again!

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

The first 15 non-negative integers are written below. The 16th number contains 4 digits! - yet it is the next *and* the last term.

No special knowledge required. Try see if you can find a pattern and then replace the question marks.

### 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 40, 46, 60, 61, 64, 80, 84, ????

Comment: Specifically, the 4th one of these sequences

Comment: @hexomino aaah, yes it does!